# Using ref in express js to make a relationship in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, crud, rest

I have tried to make the relationship between two models in node js express app. I used the world **ref** to retrieve the user's names who created the courses however, when I create the course from the user after login or register, it does not show anything about the user who created that course. Instead, it shows an empty **[] array**. I want to show the user full name who created that course.

User's ref in the course  model:

```
  },
  creator: [
    {
      ref: "Users",
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
  ],
```

Here I am trying to get the user who created the course:

```
//Get all courses
exports.getAllCourses = async (req, res) => {
  await Courses.find()
    .sort("-created")
    .populate("creator", "firstName lastName fullName")
    .exec((err, courses) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "All courses fetched successfully",
          result: courses,
        });
      }
    });
};
```

The result I am getting in postman:

```
{
    "message": " All courses fetched successfully",
    "result": [
        {
            "creator": [], <----- Here I am getting the user as an empty array
            "_id": "606d0f4d6051bb308089b5d2",
            "courseCode": "Math202",
            "courseName": "Math linear algebra",
            "section": "001",
            "semester": 1,
            "__v": 0
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`.populate({ path: 'creator', model: 'Users', select: 'firstName lastName fullName' });`

Comment: I am getting an empty array again. It is not working this way

Comment: `.populate('creator')` try this if you get all the records of a user in array, check if it populates and if you gave the reference correctly or not

Comment: Not working too. I have included in my question a code that shows how I reference the user in the course model. Could you please check it